# Initial foreach is 1 not 0

Tags: php

Im trying to start a 'foreach' but it starts at 1 not at 0. Why is that and how can i fix it?

```
<?php $i = 0;
foreach ($this->images as $image) {
    $i++;
    $src_image_thumb = Bt_propertyHelper::getPathImage($image->item_id, 'ssthumb', $image->filename, $this‌​->category->id); ?> 
    <li data-uk-slideshow-item="<?php echo "$i"; ?>">
        <img alt="<?php echo $image->title; ?>" src="<?php echo $src_image_thumb; ?>">
    </li> 
<?php } ?>
```

I know is probably pretty obvius but im quite a newbie.

Comment: you are probably checking after post increment `$i++`, post your entire code where you got 1

Comment: Can you tell actually what you want to do?

Comment: the output.. is for a gallery, the output is a <li> element and i use the $i variant has id.. like <li id-photo="$i">.. The first output should be <li id-photo="0"> and continue from there but it starts from 1.

Comment: `$this->images` what content it have?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh, why did you add a closing brace? This was not noted in the solution, and you should not make changes that change how the question was worded.

Comment: <?php
                                $i = 0;
                                foreach ($this->images as $image) {
                                $i++;
                                $src_image_thumb = Bt_propertyHelper::getPathImage($image->item_id,'ssthumb',$image->filename,$this->category->id);
                                ?>
            
            
            <li data-uk-slideshow-item="<?php echo "$i";?>"><img alt="<?php echo $image->title; ?>" src="<?php echo $src_image_thumb; ?>"></li>
            
            <?php } ?>

Comment: @DanielAcevedo Edit your original post, instead of posting in the comments.

Comment: @DanielAcevedo, Welcome to stackoverflow. This may be your first time here, so I recommend you check out [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question, and even take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to earn your first badge. If an answer below does answer your question, I recommend you accept it so that both you and the post can gain rep.

Answer (score 1):

First use `$i` then increment it. Do it like -

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($this->images as $image) {
     echo "<li id-photo='$i'>Values...</li>";
     $i++;
}
```

For your code it should be -

```
<?php 
  $i = 0; 
  foreach ($this->images as $image) {  
    $src_image_thumb = Bt_propertyHelper::getPathImage($image>item_id,'ssthumb',$image->filename,$this‌​->category->id); 
?> 
  <li data-uk-slideshow-item="<?php echo "$i";?>">
    <img alt="<?php echo $image->title; ?>" src="<?php echo $src_image_thumb; ?>">
  </li> 
<?php 
   $i++;
} 
?>
```

Comment: Why this wont work? It will generate like - `data-uk-slideshow-item="0"`, `data-uk-slideshow-item="1"`....

Comment: So, What is not working there?

Comment: @Uchiha You're echoing out `$i++`, there is a big difference there. It will return the value, and then increment it. He's not doing that, he's incrementing it at the top, and then echoing it out later.

Comment: @b0s3 this code works perfectly! Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Put the `$i++` at the end of the loop. It's being incremented at the top of the foreach loop, so when you access it, it will start at 1 and not 0.

Editing for clarification. Use this if you want `$i` to start at 0. You could also just start `$i` at -1, and leave the code as is.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($this->images as $image) {
    $src_image_thumb = Bt_propertyHelper::getPathImage($image->item_id,'ssthumb',$image->filename,$this‌​->category->id);
    ?>
    <li data-uk-slideshow-item="<?php echo $i;?>">
        <img alt="<?php echo $image->title; ?>" src="<?php echo $src_image_thumb; ?>">
    </li>
<?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Wait, what? Can you clarify more?

Comment: I recommend you check out the comments on OP's post, where he added the codeblock that is within the `foreach` loop

Comment: @Uchiha Seems like a pretty random jumble of php code to post if I didn't see it somewhere's else.